# replacing values with mutate_at always gives error that number of rows don't match, how to fix this?

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset where I want to replace a certain value (lets say: 5) with another value (lets say: 10), however, only in certain columns. I wanted to do this using the following code:

```
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
> df
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9

> df <- df %>% mutate_at(c(1:2), ~ replace(., 5, 10))
-
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Error: Column `V1` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 5
```

This error always seems to state that my columns have a longer length than is actually the case.

How fix this? And i'm also interested why this problem occurs!

Comment: `df %>% mutate_at(c(1:2), ~ replace(., . == 5, 10))`. Typo in `replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)) %>% 
  mutate_at(c(1:2), ~ replace(., . == 5, 10))
```

> ```
>   V1 V2 V3
> 1  1  4  7
> 2  2 10  8
> 3  3  6  9
> ```

In `replace`, you need to give a logical vector of the same length as `.`, so `. == 5`. Just `5` alone isn't meaningful (at least not how you want it to be).

What it's actually trying to do in your original code is change position 5 in each vector to 10, which extends the original vectors from `1, 2, 3` to `1, 2, 3, NA, 10`. That's the source of the error message.